# ApplozicConversation.getMessageListForContact() limit result size

Tags: android, applozic

I want to retrive messages for contact when i call this function

```
ApplozicConversation.getMessageListForContact(getAppContext(), contact.getContactIds(), null, new MessageListHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(List<Message> messageList, ApplozicException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    listOfMessages.addAll(0, messageList);
                    listener.onResult(messageList, e);
                } else {
                    listener.onResult(null, e);
                }
            }
        });
```

messageList size is 235 i need to do pagination how can i limit result size ? i'm using following SDK version for Android.

> com.applozic.communication.message:mobicomkit:5.34

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, The limit in fetching message restriction is not there however we will think about adding it.

For now, You can use the workaround to import the source code  By downloading the Applozic-Android-SDK from the GitHub project this link: 
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Next, import the module  `mobicomkit` from the downloaded GitHub project while importing it will show `mobicomkit` and `mobicommons` select both.

then in your app `Build.gradle` file add `api project(':mobicomkit')` and make sure you remove the gradle dependency `com.applozic.communication.message:mobicomkit:5.34` from your `build.gradle` file

Next, you can open the file MessageDatabaseService.java file and find the method

```
public List<Message> getMessages(Long startTime, Long endTime, Contact contact,  Channel channel, Integer conversationId) {
```

then you will see the Cursor query there you can add the limit as below

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query("sms", null, structuredNameWhere, structuredNameParamsList.toArray(new String[structuredNameParamsList.size()]), null, null, "createdAt asc limit 200");
```